# Checking to see if a filename already exists before replacing an invalid char

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
   public void FileCleanup(List<string>paths)
    {
        string regPattern = (@"[~#&!%+{}]+");
        string replacement = "";
        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);

        foreach (string files2 in paths)
            try
            {
                string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(files2);
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
                string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);
                //write to streamwriter
                System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);



            }
```

Now, my question is, how do i make sure that before the .Replace(), that the app first checks to see if the filename does NOT exist?
I noticed my app, when given these test files:  ###test.txt, #~test.txt will NOT remove invalid chars because after a rename, they will both have the same filename (test.txt).
If it does, i want it to go to another foreach loop where i switch the invalid char to a specific char (versus a blank).  Code would really help.

Thank you!

Comment: You do know that there's [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) and [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx)?

Comment: actually i'm very new to C# so no i didn't know this.

Comment: Sorry, that came over the wrong way. You should use these rather than hardcoding the illegal characters. You never know Microsoft might change them one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `File.Exists` to check to see if the file already exists. Here's the reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

So in your example:

```
string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
{
    // perform the move
    System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);
}
else
{
    // perform other action
}
```

And as ChrisF helpfully mentioned in the comments section to your question, you can use `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` and `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` for making sure the filename is valid.

Comment: does this come after the line:  string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly,sanitizedFileName); ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
{
    // The file already exists!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int replacement = 0;
while( File.Exists( sanitized ) )
{
    int lastDot = sanitized.LastIndexOf('.');
    if( lastDot < 0 )
        lastDot=sanitized.Length;
    sanitized = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
        sanitized.Substring(0,lastDot - (replacement>0?1:0)),
        replacement++,
        sanitized.Substring(lastDot)
        );
}
```

Comment: This seems to solve the collision of two renamed input filenames to the same output filename.

Comment: Please comment with downvotes, and I can delete or fix, thank you.